Can I replace a repeated verb with "do"?
Someone suggested using do instead of repeating "associate" in the second sentence.
Does this type of construction have a name in English and is it acceptable in formal writing?


People associate obesity with being unhealthy just like people associate thinness with being healthy.
People associate obesity with being unhealthy just like people do thinness with being healthy.



Both are fine, why?

You don't use "just like" to coordinate contrasting ideas. People associate obesity with being unhealthy and thinness with being healthy.

I would use just as.

I would prefer "just as they do..." - and thinness needs two 'n's.

@PhilSweet "just like" is used for analogies. I don't think it matters that the analogy is between contrasting concepts.

The only problem with either is that 'thiness' should have more in the middle. Substitution of 'do' for an already mentioned verb is standard if rather formal.

Sorry, this can't be answered as-is. Please explain more about what parts of the sentences you're concerned about. There are several problems with both sentences; by explaining your concerns you'll get answers that focus help your personal need more.

@Barmar It may be one of those quixotic prescriptivist sticking points that isn't worth fighting over, but the party line is: "It's 'like' for a phrase, 'as' for a clause. The Marlboro Man should have his manly wrists slapped and be corrected to 'Marlboros taste good as a cigarette should.'"

@AndyBonner It looks like the question is only asking about the proper way to phrase the the clause after "like", not the entire sentence structure.

@Barmar Yes; given that that's the only difference between the two, it's a reasonable guess. But it's only a guess, and obviously the other problems have already attracted input. And the OP's concerns about omitting a repeated verb can be best answered if they elaborate on the nature of those concerns. This is why questions that don't have a "clear area of concern" are off-topic; they attract answers like Robin Turner's that might not be what the OP really needs.

@AndyBonner The question specifically says "which ... is correct". That implies that one or both is correct, and the only possible point of the question can be the difference between them.

@Barmar Well, neither is "correct," so all the commenters are here nitpicking about all the errors; this is why proofreading questions are off-topic. But more to the point, even if the zone of difference is clear, if the OP can articulate what concerns they have about it, then they can be clearly addressed in a way that helps this particular user. I'm confused, are you arguing against the proofreading close-reason? That's best done in Meta. Or are you arguing that this question should not be closed? I'd like to see it well-answered, but I'm using the CV to make that possible.

@AndyBonner nothing prevents more experienced users to edit a question if they believe it is worth answering. The question has been edited, and it no longer asks which sentence is correct. I've cast my vote to reopen. What have we got to lose?

I wouldn't consider either of those sentences to be 'formal.' The 'just' in both of them really throws it off. 'Many associate a trim physique with with healthfulness (and obesity with a lack thereof).'? (unrelated, but I would also make sure and use a citation to back this assertion up)

No need to repeat "people" or the verb: "People associate obesity with being unhealthy and thinness with being healthy."

I would put it in the passive voice:

Obesity is associated with poor health just as thinness is associated with health.


This would be improved with an explanation of why you think this is better than the suggested options.

As I understand the question, you have to choose one of the given sentences, not propose a rewrite.

The OP's question isn't clear, but this doesn't seem to answer it. Note that general writing advice is off-topic here, so if the question had been "what's the best way to phrase this," that would be off-topic.
